# Visualforce and another "gotcha" with using a Map and implementing Comparable

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

Ran into another `gotcha` with Salesforce Visualforce - I implemented the Comparable interface - the `compareto` method to be specific - for a custom class so I could do a `sort()`.  That worked fine for `List<>` and `Map<>` in APEX - but I ran into an issue with using the Map in Visualforce.

For some reason, if there are two elements that are `equal` according to the `compareto` logic (ie. it returns a 0) then the `<apex:repeat>` ignores one of them.  I don't know if this is true of other iterators in Visualforce - I don't have time to look for more bugs.

Anyone have an idea of why APEX sees all of the members but VF skips the duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

Maps don't allow duplicate keys. So every time you add a value to a key that already exists, the old entry gets overwritten. It would help troubleshooting if you add your code to the question.